# Unable to add child entity - JPA OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying to add an entity to database that entity have OneToMany relationship to another entity but when I insert that entity it is saying unable to insert id because it is null.

I have mapped parent child class like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "directory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

private List<DirectoryRemarksEntity> remarks;
```

Child Entity :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DIRECTORY_ID")
@JsonIgnore
private DirectoryTableEntity directory;
```

My json looks like this:

```
 {
  "state": {
    "id": 2,
    "nameEn": "Dubai",
    "code": "DXB",
    "nameAr": "دبي"
  },
  "segment": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Government",
    "alias": "Gov"
  },
  "contactType": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "FAX"
  },
  "remarks": [
    {
      "remarkValueAR": "EN Remarks",
      "remarkValueEN": "AR RemarksEN ",
      "remarkType": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "legacy_modifieddate"
      }
    }
  ],
  "isTelSecret": 1,
  "isPublishElectroniceMedia": 0,
  "isTelPublishDa": 1,
  "isPrintARA": 0,
  "isPrintENG": 0,
  "establishmentNameEn": "Establishment Name",
  "establishmentNameAr": "",
  "establishmentSubNameEn": "Subname",
  "establishmentSubNameAr": "Arabicname",
  "contactCountryCode": "92",
  "contactNumber": "3042501110",
  "streetAR": "",
  "streetEN": "",
  "houseNumber": "",
  "flatNo": "",
  "buildingAR": "",
  "buildingEN": "",
  "proffesionAR": "",
  "proffesionEN": "",
  "latitude": "",
  "longitude": "",
  "accountProductCode": "00",
  "subSegment": "",
  "companyNameAr": "",
  "companyNameEn": "",
  "email": "",
  "url": "",
  "ISUrl": "",
  "ticketsFeesEN": "",
  "ticketsFeesAR": "",
  "timingsAR": "",
  "timingsEN": "",
  "streetEn": "SZR"
}
```

This is the error hibernate is throwing:

> > Error Msg = ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DQISAPPS"."DIRECTORY_REMARKS"."DIRECTORY_ID")
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)

Here is my rest Controller :

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<Response<DirectoryTableEntity>> save(@RequestBody DirectoryTableEntity directory){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            new Response<>(directoryService.save(directory), new Meta(SUCCESS_MESSAGE, HttpStatus.OK.value())),
            HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here is my service :

```
    @Override
public DirectoryTableEntity save(DirectoryTableEntity directory) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String user  = authService.getUsername();
    directory.setStatusId(1);
    directory.setCreatedBy(user);
    directory.setLastModifiedBy(user);
    return directoryTableRepository.save(directory);
}
```

Can anybody tell what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you add your rest controller that accepts this json and the method that calls the repository to store?

Comment: I have add the rest controller and the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationship between `DirectoryRemarksEntity` and `DirectoryTableEntity`  is bi-directional. In `JPA/Hibernate` you have to explicitly set both sides.

When the `DirectoryTableEntity` is created from json, `directory.getRemarks()` will have `DirectoryRemarksEntity` but the `remark.getDirectory()` will be `null`.

So update your service method to include `directory.getRemarks().forEach(remark -> remark.setDirectory(directory));`

```
@Override
public DirectoryTableEntity save(DirectoryTableEntity directory) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String user  = authService.getUsername();
    directory.setStatusId(1);
    directory.setCreatedBy(user);
    directory.setLastModifiedBy(user);
    directory.getRemarks().forEach(remark -> remark.setDirectory(directory));
    return directoryTableRepository.save(directory);
}
```